# Show that any graph has an independent set of size at least $\frac{n^2}{2m+n}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

I am trying to show that any graph with n vertices and m edges has an independent set of size at least: $$\frac{n^2}{2m+n}$$

I have already shown that any graph has an independent set of size at least:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{d(v_i) + 1}$$

where $d(v_i)$ is the degree of vertex $v_i$.

I am trying to deduce the first result from what I have already shown.

I know that $$\sum_{i=0}^n {(d(v_i) + 1)} = 2m + n$$ by the handshaking lemma and I reckon this will be helpful, however I'm struggling to combine it with $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{d(v_i) + 1}$ to prove the required result.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You would be done if you could show that
$$
\sum_i \frac1{d(v_i)+1}\ge \frac{n^2}{2m+n}
$$
Letting $f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$, the LHS is $\sum_i f(d(v_i))$. Use the face that the function $f(x)$ is convex.